# Building an application independent of the SQL engine used

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, pdo

I wanted to ask that if and how is it possible to make a PHP-based application independent of the SQL engine used?

(Under that I mean that the application can be executed on PostgreSQL, MySQL and maybe also Oracle SQL.)

Current idea is to leave the PDO DSN into the config file, so that the queries etc everything else stay the same, but can I face some problems in regards of CRUD actions to the tables themselves?

If I don't add any complex stuff in it, then is it possible for me to make it so that it doesn't depend on the engine at all, only has the PDO DSN for the database and that it can query everything the same way on each of the SQL engines?

Best regards!

Comment: If you want to be independent, you will have to write a 'db driver' for each of the possible engines that have the same signature.

Comment: Use Doctrine or some other ORM.

Comment: You will face some issues depending on the different dialects every SQL engine will use. There is not a fully standard "SQL" syntax common to mySQL, Oracle and others. So I agree with @ShiraNai7 you'd better not reinvent the weel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about Database Abstraction Layer. There are quite some libraries available for PHP. If you choose any of the popular frameworks, to mention Symfony or Laravel - you will have the DBAL out of the box - either Doctrine or Eloquent. Both offer similar query building functionality, IMO based on HQL.

Definitely **don't** try to write it "your way". Even if you do only simple queries the gramma is different, to mention just the types, incrementing etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you stick to a common subset of SQL which is supported by all your targeted databases, then yes, you can get away with using the same PDO instance, the same queries, and just switching the PDO DSN.

Practically speaking however, for anything but the most trivial queries, you'll probably be using some database specific features which you'll have to implement slightly differently for different databases. Simply speaking that means your code will have to execute query A if connected to MySQL but a slightly different query B if connected to Postgres.

You certainly do not want to implement that using a lot of `if..else`, instead you want to be using database specific *adapters/drivers*. In your business code you'll be calling `$database->getUserRecords()`, and depending on whether `$database` uses the MySQL or Postgres adapter the query will be slightly different. (Also see *dependency injection*.)

You can either do this by implementing those adapters by hand and tweaking the queries for each database, or use a more abstracted ORM/DBAL which can assemble the correct query on the fly using database-specific query builders. There are many existing libraries for that.